# How to create a relative link from a link with no extension in html?

Tags: html, hyperlink

In my page, the current link is

```
https://mydomain/en/tools/mytool
```

I now want to go to

```
https://mydomain/en/tools/mytool/faqs
```

How can I create an `a tag` with a `href` value that goes to `/faqs` using relative links?

I tried

```
<a href="./faqs">link</a>
```

But the result is just

```
https://mydomain/en/tools/faqs
```

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: `<a href="faqs">link</a>` <- Use that!

Comment: see comment below

Answer (score 1):

You would use just:

```
<a href="faqs">link</a>
```

Comment: I think `mytool` is treated as a file, so when I say `faqs` the browser thinks `faqs` is a file in the same directory as `mytool`.

Comment: Do you have an htaccess or other URL rewriting code in place?

Comment: no, I was hoping there is a easy solution for this, preferably without javascript.